# Index of generating set to $E(\mathbb{Q} ) /2E(\mathbb{Q} )$ can be arbitrarly large

Tags: diophantine-equations, abelian-groups, elliptic-curves

I'm trying to prove question 2.12.25 from "Elliptic Curves, Modular Forms, and Their L-Functions
by élvaro Lozano-Robledo".

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve, such that the image of the points $P_1,...,P_n \in E(\mathbb{Q})$ generate the group $E(\mathbb{Q}) / 2E(\mathbb{Q})$ (i.e. the weak mordell weil group). Let $G$ be the subgroup of $E(\mathbb{Q})$ generated by $P_1,...,P_n$.

Show that the index $[E(\mathbb{Q}): G]$ is finite, and that it can be arbitrarly large (depending only on the choice of the generators $P_1,...,P_n$).

---

Using Weak Mordell Weil theorem it is easy to see that the index is indeed finite, however I cannot figure out why it can be aritrarly large?

Isn't it true that $E(\mathbb{Q}) / G  \cong {E(\mathbb{Q})/2E(\mathbb{Q})} / {G / 2E(\mathbb{Q})}$ which is not depandent of the generators? what am i missing?

Comment: Imagine that $E(\mathbb Q) \cong \mathbb Z$. Then $P_1$ could be any odd number. In your isomorphism, it should be $G\cap 2E(\mathbb Q)/2E(\mathbb Q)$, not $G/2E(\mathbb Q)$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 - first of all thanks, I can see my mistake now. However, what if $E(\mathbb{Q})$ is not $\mathbb{Z}$, or even if the rank is 0 (then $E(\mathbb{Q})$ is finite)?